# Connecting to Jira using JerseyJiraRestClientFactory

Tags: java, rest, jira

I am trying to connect to jira using the JerseyJiraRestClientFactory from my java class. Currently this is what I have added in my code :

```
        final JerseyJiraRestClientFactory factory = new JerseyJiraRestClientFactory();
        final URI jiraServerUri = new URI("https://jira.example.com");
        final JiraRestClient restClient = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(jiraServerUri, "jiraUsername", "jiraPwd");
        final NullProgressMonitor pm = new NullProgressMonitor();
        final Issue issue = restClient.getIssueClient().getIssue("ISS-45", pm);     
        System.out.println(issue);
```

But it looks like the jvm is erroring out saying :

```
Apr 11, 2016 12:48:16 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection timed out: connect
Apr 11, 2016 12:48:16 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: Retrying request
Exception in thread "main" com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.RestClientException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.AbstractJerseyRestClient.invoke(AbstractJerseyRestClient.java:75)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.AbstractJerseyRestClient.getAndParse(AbstractJerseyRestClient.java:80)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.JerseyIssueRestClient.getIssue(JerseyIssueRestClient.java:142)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.JerseyIssueRestClient.getIssue(JerseyIssueRestClient.java:133)
    at com.project.jira.GetAllProjects.main(GetAllProjects.java:30)
```

I thought it requires proxy and so I have added proxy as the system property before connecting to the uri.

```
        System.getProperties().put("https.proxyHost", "proxyHost");
        System.getProperties().put("https.proxyPort", "proxyPwd");
        System.getProperties().put("https.proxySet", "true");
```

But it still throws the same error. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: Did you check the URL. I think the URL is wrong.

Comment: it is "https://jira.companyname.com". Thats how I connect through the browser!

Comment: Try connecting using http://JIRAURL:portNo/jira/rest/api/2/issue Have a look at documentation https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis